# What view is used here?

Tags: android-layout, android

Can some tell me, which view is used for the control, marked with red, on the image below (Viber app screenshot)?

[image]

I thought it was a split action bar, but it can't be, since the top action bar has a different style than the one below.

Comment: Use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to find out.

Comment: The uiautomatorviewer requires a device with API level 16.

Comment: For API level<16 use `hierarchyviwer`. That case you'll have to find out the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect device with `adb` while this screen is in the foreground.
2. Open a command window or terminal at `<<YOUR_SDK_PATH>>/tools` and run `uiautomatorviewer.bat`(Windows).
3. Click **`Device Screenshot`** and select the device.
4. Select the UI ("Open Keypad") and you'll see the View on the top-right pane.

**EDIT:**
For API Level below 16 use `hierarchyviewer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a normal button (which was added outside of the ViewFlipper or several different buttons for each tap)

If you have a rooted phone with a lower API-level as than 16 (otherwise use the `uiautomatorviewer`), get the .apk onto the computer (or download it somewhere). Then decompile it and look at the source-files. Maybe you can find out the wanted view (and you also have the source-code!).

Comment: I don't think it's a button, because on one of the other layouts, there are multiple icons (button's cant have multiple icons?).

Comment: really interesting, maybe there are several of them or another view.